# How do i convert output from a vader sentiment script into a dataframe for a csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vader

im looking to convert my output to a dataframe format for sentiment scores

I have an output dataframe:

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
for transcript in transcript:
    vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(transcript)
    print("{:-<65} {}".format(transcript, str(vs)))


thank you for calling my name is Britney and her the pleasure speaking with %HESITATION yes this is clearer Craddock and I just want to let you know that %HESITATION my little pumpkin passed away oh oh okay let me %HESITATION get that set up here for you then okay can you just verify for me your mailing address eleven oh five west street was in California nine five six nine five  {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.823, 'pos': 0.177, 'compound': 0.9001}
thank you %HESITATION and then %HESITATION you said pumpkin passed away if you don't mind me asking when did pumpkin patch %HESITATION in the last week and of last week okay so %HESITATION what we will do is we will cancel it effective  {'neg': 0.041, 'neu': 0.804, 'pos': 0.155, 'compound': 0.6705}
what is last week this ------------------------------------------ {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
so did you want to cancel it effective the tense so or the end of last week as in like it was Friday or Saturday %HESITATION %HESITATION %HESITATION %HESITATION the tent it was around the time okay so we will cancel it effective %HESITATION the ten just to you know make sure if there was any coverage dates if you have to submit anything we don't have to worry about that getting in the way and I do just have to read a quick verification to you okay okay so as you requested your plan for pumpkin will be canceled effective at five you worry tenth of two thousand twenty is the refund is due with the change it will be processed within seven business days and it also gives me a confirmation number did you want to write that down or just save it here on file  {'neg': 0.038, 'neu': 0.768, 'pos': 0.193, 'compound': 0.9676}
%HESITATION ----------------------------------------------------- {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}
please leave it there on file all right and then did you have additional questions while I had you Clara  {'neg': 0.059, 'neu': 0.829, 'pos': 0.112, 'compound': 0.2732}
%HESITATION no no I don't I just want to let you people know that it is a pumpkin is gone and %HESITATION %HESITATION squeaker message %HESITATION %HESITATION I said if you have any anything you have questions about or you need to talk about something you feel free to call okay Clara okay okay good day okay thank you bye thank you bye bye  {'neg': 0.077, 'neu': 0.667, 'pos': 0.256, 'compound': 0.9038}
```

As you see all the output is together. I want this output to be in a format where the sentence is shown and then the associated scores are shown in columns neg neutral positive and compound like a dataframe not a running sentence. How do I convert the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
text = ['She is pretty', 'He is ugly']
 scores = []
for txt in text:
    vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(txt)
    scores.append(vs)
data = pd.DataFrame(text, columns= ['Text'])
data2 = pd.DataFrame(scores)
final_dataset= pd.concat([data,data2], axis=1)
```

I hope this code helps you!

Comment: Hi, when I implement this code in mine I get an error 
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! when I run data = pd.Dataframe(text, columns= ['Text'])

Comment: This code works for me. Please enter the parameters correctly!